# Eclipse CDT- go to next line in #define statement

Tags: c, eclipse, c-preprocessor

I'm working in Eclipse-CDT and I have the following #define statement:

```
#define IS_ARGUMENT_NULL(arg) if (NULL == arg) {fprintf(stderr, "%s is NULL", #arg); bool isNull = true;}
```

The line is too long for me (I need to keep up to max 80 characters per line) and I was wondering how could I go down a line with the code to compile ok.
I tried pressing enter and getting

```
#define IS_ARGUMENT_NULL(arg) if (NULL == arg) {fprintf(stderr, "%s is NULL", #arg);
bool isNull = true;}
```

but it won't compile. Says "expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token" on the second line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash (`\`) is the line continuation character.

```
#define IS_ARGUMENT_NULL(arg) \
    if (NULL == arg) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "%s is NULL", #arg); \
        bool isNull = true; \
    }
```

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Object-like-Macros.html#Object-like-Macros):

> The macro's body ends at the end of the ‘#define’ line. You may
>   continue the definition onto multiple lines, if necessary, using
>   backslash-newline. When the macro is expanded, however, it will all
>   come out on one line.